# c# How to copy AD memberships from an existing user to a new one?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, active-directory, membership

I have the following code that creates a user in the active directory. The only thing I have left to do is to copy the memberships from another user (Member of section(file server access and so on)). I just can't figure out how to do this and can't find anything about this online...

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textboxOu.Text = 
    "OU=Common,OU=Users,OU=NLEML,OU=NL,OU=_Sites,DC=testdomain,DC=nl";
    textboxAdminUsername.Text = @"kuiken\";
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string stringDomainName = 
        System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties.
        GetIPGlobalProperties().DomainName;
        PrincipalContext PrincipalContext4 = new 
        PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, stringDomainName,   
        textboxOu.Text, ContextOptions.SimpleBind, 
        textboxAdminUsername.Text, 
        passwordboxAdminPassword.Text);
        UserPrincipal UserPrincipal1 = new UserPrincipal(PrincipalContext4, 
        textboxLonOnName.Text, 
        passwordboxUserPass.Text, true);

        //User Logon Name
        string homefolder = @"\\kuiken\users$\" + textboxLonOnName.Text;
        string emailadress = txtboxMail.Text + "@test.network";

        UserPrincipal1.UserPrincipalName = textboxSamAccountName.Text;
        UserPrincipal1.Name = textboxName.Text;
        UserPrincipal1.GivenName = textboxGivenName.Text;
        UserPrincipal1.Surname = textboxSurname.Text;
        UserPrincipal1.DisplayName = textboxName.Text;
        UserPrincipal1.Description = textboxDescription.Text;
        UserPrincipal1.EmailAddress = emailadress;
        UserPrincipal1.EmployeeId = txtID.Text;
        UserPrincipal1.VoiceTelephoneNumber = textboxPhonenumber.Text;
        UserPrincipal1.HomeDrive = "H:";
        UserPrincipal1.HomeDirectory = homefolder;




        if (radiobuttonEnable.Checked == true)
        {
            UserPrincipal1.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            UserPrincipal1.Enabled = false;
        }
        UserPrincipal1.Save();

        MessageBox.Show("AD account created succesfuly");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

I want to use a textbox with the username for example of the existing user as the input.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `UserPrincipal` that you want to copy the groups from, then you use the [`GetGroups()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principal.getgroups?view=netframework-4.7.1) method to find all the groups it's a member of.

Something like this (`sourceAccount` is the account you want to copy from):

```
foreach (GroupPrincipal group in sourceAccount.GetGroups()) {
    group.Members.Add(UserPrincipal1);
    group.Save();
}
```

Comment: Alright I think this is the right direction, I would like to get the sourceAccount from a textbox imput. But what value would I need to use from the source account, maybe the logon name? Any idea how to get this to work?

Comment: You can use `UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal.findbyidentity

Comment: Thank you for the response, I got this bit working I think. However it gives an error on "Members" ('Principal' does not contain a definition for 'Members' and no extension method 'Members' accepting a first argument of type 'Principal' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?))

Comment: Oh, I see. `GetGroups()` returns a collection of `Principal`, so you have to cast it to `GroupPrincipal`. I updated my code example.

Comment: Yes that fixed the error. However I think there is something going wrong when calling the sourceaccount. Do you have any comments on this line:

    `UserPrincipal sourceAccount = 
    UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(PrincipalContext4, IdentityType.Name, 
    copyfromTxtBox.Text);`

The last thing it does before it gives an error is something with the group "domain users"...  I would like to give the exact error but it is gibberish...

Comment: It might be trying to add the new user to the 'Domain Users' group. If you're comfortable doing so, you could put `group.Save()` in a try/catch block and just ignore the exception (or log it, if you want, but it'll probably always happen on 'Domain Users' at least)